# Density of ratios of an arbitrary increasing sequence of prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

It is well known that the set $\left\{ \frac{p}{q} : p,q \textrm{ prime numbers }\right\}$ is dense in the positive real numbers $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Not having a background in number theory, I ask myself the following:

Let $\mathbf{p}:=\{p_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of prime numbers.

Is there any sensible condition I could impose on $\mathbf{p}:=\{p_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ such that the set $ A(\mathbf{p}):=\left\{ \frac{p_n}{p_m} : m,n\geq 1\right\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$?

Comment: Certainly, this is obvious. Or you meant to include some more assumptions.

Comment: Could you point out a good reference or provide a quick explanation why the last sentence of my post is obvious?

Comment: I think Chris Ramsey means it's obvious the answer to your question is in the negative. E.g., start with $p_1 := 2$ and recursively define $p_{n+1}$ in such a way that $p_{n+1} \ge 2p_n$ (which is always possible, of course). Then $A(\mathbf p) \subseteq \{1\} \cup {]0,1/2]} \cup [2,\infty[$. (I'm afraid the question is not appropriate for MO.)

Comment: As you are are seeking sensible conditions etc., it seems reasonable to me that an answer to your question should be phrased in the "language of densities", but I don't think there is much known out there in this sense. E.g., let $\mu^\ast$ be the asymptotic density relative to $\bf P$ (= the set of primes), viz. the fnc $\mathcal P({\bf P})\to{\bf R}:X\mapsto\limsup_n\frac{1}{\pi(n)}|X\cap[1,n]|$, where $\pi$ is the prime counting fnc. Then, it's tempting to conjecture that for $X\subseteq\bf P$ the ratio set of $X$ is dense in ${\bf R}^+$ if $\mu^\ast(X)+\mu_\ast(X) \ge 1$, where (...)

Comment: $\mu_\ast$ is the conjugate of $\mu^\ast$, i.e. the fnc $\mathcal P({\bf P})\to{\bf R}:X\mapsto 1−\mu^\ast({\bf P}\setminus X)$. One reason why this is tempting is that the analogous result with the upper asymptotic density in place of $\mu^\ast$ (and its conjugate in place of $\mu_\ast$) is, in fact, true, see O. Strauch and J. T. Tóth, *Asymptotic density of $A \subseteq \mathbf N$ and density of the ratio set $R(A)$*, Acta Arith. **87** (1998), No. 1, 67-78.

Comment: @GregMartin. Isn't $\mu^\ast(X)=\mu_\ast(X)=0$ if $|X| < \infty$? Perhaps it's me who is missing something.

Comment: got it, I was indeed misunderstanding $\mu_*$

Comment: Incidentally, an older result by T. Šalát (*On ratio sets of sets of natural numbers*, Acta Arith. **15** (1969), No. 3, 273-278; *Corrigendum to the paper ``On ratio sets of sets of natural numbers''*, ibid. **16** (1969), 103) suggests as a starting point for further investigations to prove/disprove that if $μ^\ast(X)=\mu_\ast(X)>0$ or $\mu^\ast(X) = 1$ for $X \subseteq \bf P$ (I'm continuing with the notation used in my previous comments), then the ratio set of $X$ is dense in ${\bf R}^+$.

Comment: For the record, I've just learned of an erratum to the paper of Strauch and Tóth I mentioned above, namely: O. Strauch and J. T. Tóth, *Corrigendum to Theorem 5 of the paper “Asymptotic density of $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ and density of the ratio set $R(A)$ (Acta Arith. 87 (1998), 67--78)*, Acta Arith. **103** (2002), No. 2, 169-189 (https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/103/2).